# Laravel eloquent - order by starting string

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Imagine that I have 3 users and I want to filter then by the name with "Robert"

"Albert Robert Wilson", "Robert Megan", "Willian Joe"

I want my sql to find all records that contain `Robert`, but ordered in a way that `Robert Magan` is at the beginning cause it starts with the keyword and next comes `Albert Robert Wilso`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide an example model/table name and column name in your question. But let's say model is `User` and column is `name`. I think something like this would work (not tested):

```
User::where('name', 'like', '%Robert%')->orderBy(\DB:raw('POSITION("Robert" IN name)', 'asc')->get();
```

But please be careful not to create SQL injection vulnerabilities!

Comment: Ele me deu um erro de syntax `Syntax error or access violation` `near ') asc, created_at desc limit 20 offset 0' `

Comment: Ohh I solved it `POSITION("Robert" IN name)` edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using some raw mysql and string manipulation in order to sort by the first word.

Another way would be to split the keyword and the remaining or complete string into two separate columns, then ordering by the keyword column.